# How to search for specific classes in Microsoft Visual Studio Help viewer

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I came from XCode world, so there was no problem in searching for specific class in specific section of documentation. However, I can't find way to find classes in documentation in Help Viewer.

For example, I search for List class. When I type "List" in search field, I see too many unrelated information on all tabs (index, search, contents).

[image: Help View list]

As you can see, there's links to the List Constructor, but not link to List classes.

Is there an option (or search argument) that could help to find specific classes in Help viewer ?

Comment: Use the *Index* tab instead of Search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I don't use the offline Help anymore, but searching for `List Class` or hitting <kbd>F1</kbd> right from the editor on the Type brings you directly to the right page:

```
public List<string> list = new List<string>();
         A
         L Hit F1 here
```

If you're looking for a class simply adding "Class" or in case of an interface searching for "Interface" next to the keyword usually does the trick. If looking for all classes that inherit from, it's best to search for the common parent, on that page you'll find an overview of all classes that inherit from that class in the base class library.